# JSP return nothing due to to datalist

Tags: jsp, primefaces

I am trying to displays the list of the object in the JSP using primafaces, but nothing is displays. I am pretty sure that the list is not null.
Code of readAllPilot:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>read all pilot </title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:dataList id="datalist" var="pilot" value="#{pilotController.list}" itemType="disc">  
            <f:facet name="header">  
                <h:outputText value="Basic Message List"/>  
            </f:facet>  
            <h:outputText value="#{pilot.idPilot},#{pilot.name}" ></h:outputText>  
        </p:dataList>

    </h:form> 
</h:body>
```

This is only part of the code for better clarity
**PilotController Class:**

```
      public class PilotController {
     Pilot pilot;
     private List<Pilot> list;
     public List<Pilot> getList() {
            return list;
        }
     public void setList(List<Pilot> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }
       @PostConstruct
        protected void init() {
            pilot = new Pilot();
            list = re.catchThemAllPilot();

        }
    }
```

Could you please give me any adivce?

Comment: Are you sure this `PilotController` object is exposed to the view? Is it meant to be a managed bean, or CDI dependency? No annotation is present on that class, so chances are it's evaluating to null.

Comment: Yes, for example creating Pilot in databases works corectly

Comment: Where's the code that creates objects? JSF won't know about your bean unless you make it a managed bean of some sort and expose it to a scope... How does that work?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I have updated the code

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I forgot about it, I had it in the code and it still does not work

Comment: Are you **sure** you are using PrimeFaces with JSP? Then you have a very old PF version. And _"pretty sure that the list is not null."_... **pretty sure**? Try being 100% sure

Comment: I guess you are using spring bean as managed bean, faces-config.xml you have to specify it

Comment: also jsp and primefaces is not a good pair. You can use xhtml or jsf extension

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez: Extension has nothing to do with the technology... I assume you meant using 'facelets' instead of JSP. And where did you 'understand' Spring is being used?

Comment: I only guessed @Postconstruct annotation exists in Spring and JSF so I can not make the right decision but I hope he/she uses spring for CDI. Postconstruct annotation is from common-annotations.jar so it is just a guess

Comment: I hope he/she uses CDI instead of spring... And `@Postconstruct` exists in CDI and EJB as well (and in guice and other injection frameworks)

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own view scope if you want to use view scope or you can use predefined scopes.

In faces-config.xml you can write below code.

```
<el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>



@ManagedBean(name = "pilotController ")
@Scope("view")
public class PilotController {
     Pilot pilot;
     private List<Pilot> list;
     public List<Pilot> getList() {
            return list;
        }
     public void setList(List<Pilot> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }
       @PostConstruct
        protected void init() {
            pilot = new Pilot();
            list = re.catchThemAllPilot();

        }
    }
```